# Sql Server : Select query with calculation on rows one after another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join, inventory-management

**Table** `PURCHASE(PDate, ItemName, PQty, Rate)`

```
PDate       | ItemName     | PQty  | Rate
============================================
01-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 06    | 05,000
01-04-2015  | Laptop       | 07    | 30,000
03-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 03    | 06,000
04-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 08    | 07,000
04-04-2015  | Laptop       | 03    | 40,000
05-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 05    | 04,000
```

**Table** `SALES(SDate, ItemName, SQty)`

```
SDate       | ItemName     | SQty
=================================
02-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 02
03-04-2015  | Laptop       | 03
03-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 05
04-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 07
04-04-2015  | Laptop       | 03
06-04-2015  | Laptop       | 02
```

**SQL**

- Here we need to view the Remaining Items and their Stock Values (PQty*Rate) from **PURCHASE Table** after sales. (**Closing Stock**)
- The select query should do the process here.
- The **PURCHASE** table's PQty should be deducted **One by One**, **Top to Bottom** in Ascending order of PDate based on the **SALES table's** SQty **One by One**, **Top to Bottom** in Ascending order of Date.
- The PQty of **PURCHASE Table** should not become 0 (Zero) Which is ofcourse.
- Incase, if the PQty reaches to Zero, Deduct the remaining SQty of **SALES** from the next row of **PURCHASE Table's** PQty in the list.
- The last row may have a negative value if no more rows are available.
- Condition between the tables is done **WHERE SALES.ItemName LIKE PURCHASE.ItemName**

**Table** `EXPECTED SELECT QUERY RESULT (Date, ItemName, Qty, Rate, ProductValue)`

```
PDate       | ItemName     | PQty  | Rate   | ProductValue
===========================================================
01-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 00    | 05,000 |      0.00
01-04-2015  | Laptop       | 00    | 30,000 |      0.00
03-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 00    | 06,000 |      0.00
04-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 03    | 07,000 | 21,000.00
04-04-2015  | Laptop       | 02    | 40,000 | 80,000.00
05-04-2015  | Mobile Phone | 05    | 04,000 | 20,000.00
```

How can I sort out this problem?

Comment: Can you provide ddl and sample data in a consumable format? sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to start. Also, define "Top to Bottom". What is the order? There doesn't seem to be anything in the data you provided to get the order of rows as posted. This sounds like it might be a running total problem so the version of sql server would be important too as the method for doing that varies greatly before and after sql 2012.

Comment: Top to Bottom is ASC order of Date. Question is edited.

Comment: what zeroes in Qty and ProductValue of first 3 rows in result table mean?

Comment: Once when the products are purchased they are added to the PURCHASE table. When the items are sold they are deducted from the PURCHASE table date wise. The First Three rows of PURCHASE are Zero because those items are sold.

Comment: @shibormot, If you see in SALES table- 14 Mobile Phones and 8 Laptops are sold.
Therefore the first 2 row of Mobile Phones (6+3) and 5 Mobile Phones from 4th row are sold.
Total 8 Laptops are sold which made 2nd row i,e Laptop 0 Qty and 5th Row 2.

Comment: This is a typical running total type of problem. Which version of sql server? Have you created some ddl and sample yet ofr us to work with?

Comment: Its SQL Server - SQL Express Instance 2008

Comment: I am new to sql fiddle. Should I create the table there? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT PDate, ItemName, MPQty, PQty, ISNULL(SQty,0) AS SQty,
ISNULL((CASE WHEN SQTY>=PQty THEN 0 WHEN (SQty+MPQty)>PQty THEN PQty-SQty ELSE MPQty END),0) AS Qty, Rate,
(ISNULL((CASE WHEN SQTY>=PQty THEN 0 WHEN (SQty+MPQty)>PQty THEN PQty-SQty ELSE MPQty END),0)*Rate) AS PValue FROM
(SELECT P.PDate AS PDate, P.ItemName AS ItemName, P.PQty AS MPQty,
(SELECT SUM(P1.PQty) FROM PURCHASE P1 WHERE P1.ItemName=P.ItemName AND P1.PDate<=P.PDate) AS PQty,
(SELECT SUM(S1.SQty) FROM SALES S1 WHERE S1.ItemName=P.ItemName) AS SQty,    
P.Rate AS Rate FROM PURCHASE P)X ORDER BY Pdate
```